# console application where the user has 5 tries to guess number between 1 and 100

Tags: c#, random

I have created a console application where the user has 5 tries to guess number between 1 and 100. After 5 guesses the game ends, but I don’t know how to introduce at the 5th wrong intent something like “you have achieved maximum of guesses! The answer was number (X). I have tried different ways ,but is not working. This is my program

```
using System;

namespace Guessing_Game_4
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var number = new Random().Next(1, 100);
            Console.WriteLine("Try and guess any number between 1-100. You have 5 guesses Max!");

            for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                int guess = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());               
                if (guess == number)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("You got it!");
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(guess + " is not correct! Try again!");
                }   
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Consider using a while loop

Comment: `new Random().Next(1, 100) is poor for two reasons. (1) it's bad practice to `new` up multiple instances as it can lead to duplicate values. (2) If you want numbers from 1 to 100 you need to put `.Next(1, 101)`.

Answer (score 0):

**Here some Sample code**
**This might help**

```
        for( i=10;i>0 ; i--) {
        System.out.println("    === you have " + i +" Guesses left ===");

        int guess = scanner.nextInt();
        if (random_number < guess) System.out.println("Smaller than guess  " + guess);
        if (random_number > guess) System.out.println("Greater  than guess " + guess);
        if (random_number == guess)
        {
            result = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (result)
    {
        System.out.println("You WON in "+(10-i) +" tries ");
        System.out.println("******* CONGRATULATIONS **************************************");
        System.out.println("*********************** YOU WON **********************");
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("The random number was   "+random_number);
        System.out.println("**************************  OPPS You loose **************************************** ");
        System.out.println("You are near it TRY Next time ************ GOOD LUCK ");
        System.out.println("You are near it TRY Nexttime***********NEXTTIME********");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If that's all your program does, you can do the following trick. Print your message after the for loop, but now the problem is that you get the message in all cases. The trick is to `return` from the `Main` (instead of `break`ing the loop) on a correct guess:

```
Console.WriteLine("You got it!");
return;
```

---

If you've some other code to execute that returning from `Main` won't be a good solution, you can do the following:

1. Create a variable before the for loop. Let's call it `isCorrectAnswer` and set it to false in the beginning.
2. At the point where he answers correctly, set `isCorrectAnswer` to `true` before `break`ing the loop.
3. After the loop, check for that variable:

   ```
   if (!isCorrectAnswer)
   {
       Console.WriteLine($"you have achieved maximum of guesses! The answer was number {number}.");
   }
   ```

Comment: Thank you, Youssef13,  it was helpful

Answer (score 0):

1. You have to have an int outside of your loop like this : `int wrongAnswersCount = 0;`
2. When the user enter a wrong number you
   should add one unit to your variable `wrongAnswersCount++;`
3. In the start of the loop, you should check if the user reached the maximum amount of gueses or not, if yes break the loop and say the answer.

Your code will be something like this :

```
using System;

namespace Guessing_Game_4
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var number = new Random().Next(1, 100);
            Console.WriteLine("Try and guess any number between 1-100. You have 5 guesses Max!");
            int wrongAnswersCount = 0;
            for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                if(wrongAnswersCount == 5)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"you have achieved maximum of guesses! The answer was number {number}");

                    break;
                }
                int guess = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                if (guess == number)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("You got it!");
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(guess + " is not correct! Try again!");
                    wrongAnswersCount++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

class Program

```
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
             var number = new Random().Next(1, 100);
             Console.WriteLine("Try and guess any number between 1-100. You have 5 guesses Max!");

            for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++)   
          {
              int guess = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());               
             if (guess == number && i!=5)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You got it!");
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine(guess + " is not correct! Try again!");
            }  
            
        }
            Console.WriteLine(" the maximam guse");        
        
    }
```

}
//Try this one

Comment: Try this one I add simple instruction